# Regular expression limit a match with string matched before

Tags: php, regex

I need match a space but limit the matched with space with some condition..

```
Source :
Code AS-277 Red/Yellow
Code AS 278 Red:
Code AS 279;
Code AS-280 red;
Code AS 279/

UPDATE :
Needed Result:
1. match all word [\w] and few special char [ _-+*] for code 
2. Stop char is [/;)] and COLOR CONSTAN [BLUE|YELLOW|ETC]
3. case insensitive

AS-277 
AS 278
AS 279 
AS-280
```

I write on regex101.com
https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/2

Comment: Is it always `AS`? Is it also always 3 digits? What are all the possible characters that could be found between those two sections?

Comment: Maybe [`'~Code\s+\K[A-Z]+[-\s]\d+~`](https://regex101.com/r/IQ3wMO/1) will work better.

Comment: no.. sorry for simple sample.. @chris85 answer work for me..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my sample to simple. i got another problem :( can you help on this link on regex101  https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/6

Comment: Check [the `Code\s+\K[A-Z0-9]+(?:[-\s][0-9A-Z]+)*\b` demo](https://regex101.com/r/vYcvJ3/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that it.. i need \K. its very hard explain regex :D its part of meta sequences right.. Thanks a lot Wiktor..

Comment: @KetutWidarta Please consider accepting the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Ok. this my first SO question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
'~Code\s+([\w+*]+(?:[-\s][\w+*]+)*?\b)\s?(?:red|blue|green|yellow|[);/])~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtJpPy/1)

**Details**

- `Code` - a substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `[\w+*]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_`, `*` or `+`
- `(?:[-\s][\w+*]+)*?` - zero or more (but as few as possible) sequences of:

  - `[-\s]` - a `-` or whitespace
  - `[\w+*]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_`, `*` or `+`
- `\b` - a word boundary (i.e. there must be a non-word char (non-letter, non-digit and non-`_`)
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `(?:red|blue|green|yellow|[);/])` - one of the alternatives: `red`, `blue`, `green`, `yellow` (add more after `|`), or `[);/]` - a `)`, `;` or `/`.

Grab Group 1 value upon a match.

Comment: hi @Wiktor why not work when case insensitive.. Demo : https://regex101.com/r/vYcvJ3/3

Comment: @KetutWidarta Do you mean to ask why `code T1_GPlus)` is not matched?  Because there is no word boundary after `G`.At this moment, you need to define the requirements. I assumed you only need to match the uppercase letters.

Comment: I update mys question for more spesific.. Needed Result:
1. match all word [\w] and few special char [ _-+*] for code 
2. Stop char is [/;)] and COLOR CONSTAN [BLUE|YELLOW|ETC]
3. case insensitive

Comment: thanks wiktor.. my best try is Code\s+(\K[\w\-\+\*]+(?:[-\s][0-9A-Z]+)*\b)[ ]?(?:red|BLUE|RED|\)|;)   but still not match with backslash if i put backslash as stop. other break.. demo https://regex101.com/r/vYcvJ3/4

Comment: code ([\w\s\-_+*]+)((?: RED| BLUE|\)|;|:))   << My first regex.. did not capture backslash..

Comment: Great.. Work Perfectly.. Thanks a lot Wiktor.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^.*Code (AS[- ]\d+).*$/m', '$1', $string);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/4

or

```
preg_match_all('/Code (AS[- ]\d+)/, $string, $matches);
```

and then `$matches[1]` will have all your matches.

Both regexes look for `Code AS`, then a hyphen or space, and then at least one number (if decimal places are limited a range can be applied `{1,3}`). The first regex goes line by line. The second just captures each match.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/5

Comment: Hi @chris85 Your answer work for me.. but i have some problem if data change..  please look at https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/6

Comment: Can you define the pattern a bit more? Perhaps https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/8 does it?

Comment: Thanks A lot chris.. the problem is i need matching the code with [\w\s_-]+  for all string and space and few special char.. sample here.. https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/9

Comment: @KetutWidarta With that character class you are allowing a lot of characters though, you need to be more restrictive. Use optional non-capturing groups.

Comment: Hi cris.  \K meta sequences.. from wiktor comment on my question.. That i mean.. very hard to explain rexex question.. :D Thanks for your help.. https://regex101.com/r/vYcvJ3/1

Comment: If Wiktor answer resolves your question you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following your needed result, try this:

```
AS[- ][0-9]{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
Code (AS[ -]\d{3})
```

It's

- the word Code
- AS followed by a space or hypen
- 3 numbers

Here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/S6mvZF/3

Good luck!